# What format do I use with moment to give me same string as `new Date()`?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm using `moment()` and want to know if there's a shortcut to give me the same date string as `new Date()` would give me.

I have to do some timezone conversions so using moment.js makes that easier, but I need the same date format: `Thu Oct 06 2016 23:08:53 GMT-0700 (PDT)` as the native Date object would give me.

I would assume there is a shortcut for this, but I can't find it.

`moment.tz('America/New_York').format('???')`

Comment: [*new Date()*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring) creates a Date object, not a string. If you want the format returned by the default *toString* method, that is implementation dependent and varies.

Comment: if you do it in the console it returns the date. what different implementations are there?

Comment: There are many, many implementations of ECMAScript. Each may produce a different string. Even different versions of an implementation may differ.

Comment: Ok thanks. The API I'm using requires this format. So I guess a shortcut would be unreliable.

Comment: You have an API the requires that format? Normally API developers would go the ISO8601 way, as that's more or a less a standard for exchanging dates.

Comment: I didn't create the api. But they are just allowing the client to pass in `new Date()` string as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a shortcut however this gives the string I need:

```
moment.tz('America/New_York').format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ (z)')
```

from the docs: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Returns: `Fri Oct 07 2016 02:25:17 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

Comment: So that's hardcoded to people in the US, in that particular timezone. Probably not going to work for people in other timezones, with other date formats, etc.

Comment: timezone is irrelevant. that's why I use `moment.tz()`

Answer (score 0):

if you have no idea which timezone the browser is currently in, you can try moment.tz.guess(), it isn't 100% correct for timezone offset that has multiple names though:

```
var d = moment()._d;
d.toString().replace(/\([\w ]+\)$/, moment.tz(d, moment.tz.guess()).format('(z)'));
```

Answer (score -1):

The date format you're referring to, depends on the culture/language of your browser. That aside, if you want the same format as the standard new Date().toString() returns, you just use the toString() method on the moment object, without any arguments:

```
moment().toString();
```

Source: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-string/

Comment: This is missing the timezone.

Comment: So what you're actually asking about, is the abbreviation of the timezone? The timezone is there alright, it's GMT plus/minus whatever.